# Crouching in python platformer with pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm making a game for my final project in my python/pygame class. I've run into issues with a "crouching" ability. I want to be able to change the size of the player, but as it stands the only thing that changes is the sprite on top.

My class is using this specific example from [this](http://programarcadegames.com/python_examples/en/sprite_sheets/) site:

How can I scale or change the size of the player to fit the sprite and be able to change it back whenever I "uncrouch"?

Not sure which parts are relevant but here's my code (I apologize for it being so frankenstein-y):

```
class Bink(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """ This class represents the bar at the bottom that the player
    controls. """

    # -- Methods
    def __init__(self):
        """ Constructor function """

        # Call the parent's constructor
        super().__init__()

        # -- Attributes
        # Set speed vector of player
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0

        # Set fall rate
        self.y_speedup = .45

        # Double jump functions
        self.jump_no = 0

        # Set the players height and length
        self.length = 40
        self.height = 60

        # Set crouching to false
        self.crouching = False

        # This holds all the images for the animated walk left/right
        # of our player
        self.walking_frames_l = []
        self.walking_frames_r = []

        self.standing_frames_l = []
        self.standing_frames_r = []

        self.jumping_frames_l = []
        self.jumping_frames_r = []

        self.falling_frames_l = []
        self.falling_frames_r = []

        self.crouching_frames_l = []
        self.crouching_frames_r = []

        # What direction is the player facing?
        self.direction = "Right"

        # What 'state' is the player in
        self.state = "Stand"

        # List of sprites we can bump against
        self.level = None

        sprite_sheet = SpriteSheet("player_sprite_sheet.png")

        # Load all the right walking images into a list
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(419, 65, 40, 60)
        self.walking_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(460, 65, 40, 60)
        self.walking_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(501, 65, 40, 60)
        self.walking_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(542, 65, 40, 60)
        self.walking_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(583, 65, 40, 60)
        self.walking_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(624, 65, 40, 60)
        self.walking_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(665, 65, 40, 60)
        self.walking_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(706, 65, 40, 60)
        self.walking_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(747, 65, 40, 60)
        self.walking_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(788, 65, 40, 60)
        self.walking_frames_r.append(image)

        # Load all the left walking images

        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(419, 0, 40, 60)
        self.walking_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(460, 0, 40, 60)
        self.walking_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(501, 0, 40, 60)
        self.walking_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(542, 0, 40, 60)
        self.walking_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(583, 0, 40, 60)
        self.walking_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(624, 0, 40, 60)
        self.walking_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(665, 0, 40, 60)
        self.walking_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(706, 0, 40, 60)
        self.walking_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(747, 0, 40, 60)
        self.walking_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(788, 0, 40, 60)
        self.walking_frames_l.append(image)

        # Load all the left standing sprites
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(0, 0, 40, 60)
        self.standing_frames_l.append(image)

        # Load all the right standing sprites
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(419, 195, 40, 60)
        self.standing_frames_r.append(image)

        # Load all the left jumping sprites
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(0, 65, 40, 60)
        self.jumping_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(41, 65, 40, 60)
        self.jumping_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(82, 65, 40, 60)
        self.jumping_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(123, 65, 40, 60)
        self.jumping_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(164, 65, 40, 60)
        self.jumping_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(205, 65, 40, 60)
        self.jumping_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(246, 65, 40, 60)
        self.jumping_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(287, 65, 40, 60)
        self.jumping_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(328, 65, 40, 60)
        self.jumping_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(369, 65, 40, 60)
        self.jumping_frames_l.append(image)

        # Load all the right jumping sprites
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(419, 130, 40, 60)
        self.jumping_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(460, 130, 40, 60)
        self.jumping_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(501, 130, 40, 60)
        self.jumping_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(542, 130, 40, 60)
        self.jumping_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(583, 130, 40, 60)
        self.jumping_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(624, 130, 40, 60)
        self.jumping_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(665, 130, 40, 60)
        self.jumping_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(706, 130, 40, 60)
        self.jumping_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(747, 130, 40, 60)
        self.jumping_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(788, 130, 40, 60)
        self.jumping_frames_r.append(image)

        # Load all left falling sprites
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(0, 130, 40, 60)
        self.falling_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(41, 130, 40, 60)
        self.falling_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(82, 130, 40, 60)
        self.falling_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(123, 130, 40, 60)
        self.falling_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(164, 130, 40, 60)
        self.falling_frames_l.append(image)

        # Load all right falling sprites
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(205, 130, 40, 60)
        self.falling_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(246, 130, 40, 60)
        self.falling_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(287, 130, 40, 60)
        self.falling_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(328, 130, 40, 60)
        self.falling_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(369, 130, 40, 60)
        self.falling_frames_r.append(image)

        # Load all the left crouching sprites
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(0, 195, 45, 40)
        self.crouching_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(46, 195, 45, 40)
        self.crouching_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(92, 195, 45, 40)
        self.crouching_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(138, 195, 45, 40)
        self.crouching_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(184, 195, 45, 40)
        self.crouching_frames_l.append(image)

        # Load all right crouching sprites
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(0, 240, 45, 40)
        self.crouching_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(46, 240, 45, 40)
        self.crouching_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(92, 240, 45, 40)
        self.crouching_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(138, 240, 45, 40)
        self.crouching_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(184, 240, 45, 40)
        self.crouching_frames_r.append(image)

        # Set the image the player starts with
        self.image = self.standing_frames_r[0]

        # Set a reference to the image rect.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Build a hitbox that objects collide with
        self.hitbox = self.rect.inflate(0, 0)

        # Add or subtract to see if the player is crouching
        self.is_crouching = 0

    def update(self):
        """ Move the player. """
        # Gravity
        self.calc_grav()

        # Set the hitbox on top of the player
        self.hitbox.center = self.rect.center

        # Check for the direction
        if self.change_x < 0:
            self.direction = "Left"
        elif self.change_x > 0:
            self.direction = "Right"

        # Check for the state
        # See if we hit anything
        self.rect.y += 2
        platform_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
        self.rect.y -= 2

        # If it is ok to jump, set our speed upwards
        if len(platform_hit_list) > 0 or self.hitbox.bottom >= SCREEN_HEIGHT and self.change_x == 0:
            self.state = "Stand"
        elif len(platform_hit_list) > 0 or self.hitbox.bottom >= SCREEN_HEIGHT and self.change_x != 0:
            self.state = "Walk"
        elif self.change_y < 0 or self.change_y < 0 and self.change_x != 0:
            self.state = "Jump"
        elif self.change_y > 0 or self.change_y > 0 and self.change_x != 0:
            self.state = "Fall"
        if self.is_crouching == 1:
            self.state = "Crouch"

        # Move left/right
        self.rect.x += self.change_x
        x_pos = self.rect.x + self.level.world_shift
        y_pos = self.rect.y + self.level.world_shift

        # "If" in 'this' state and 'this' direction use 'that' sprite list for reference
        if self.direction == "Right" and self.state == "Stand":
            frame = (x_pos // 30) % len(self.standing_frames_r)
            self.image = self.standing_frames_r[frame]
        elif self.direction == "Left" and self.state == "Stand":
            frame = (x_pos // 30) % len(self.standing_frames_l)
            self.image = self.standing_frames_l[frame]

        elif self.direction == "Right" and self.state == "Walk":
            frame = (x_pos // 30) % len(self.walking_frames_r)
            self.image = self.walking_frames_r[frame]
        elif self.direction == "Left" and self.state == "Walk":
            frame = (x_pos // 30) % len(self.walking_frames_l)
            self.image = self.walking_frames_l[frame]

        elif self.direction == "Right" and self.state == "Jump":
            frame = (y_pos // 30) % len(self.jumping_frames_r)
            self.image = self.jumping_frames_r[frame]
        elif self.direction == "Left" and self.state == "Jump":
            frame = (y_pos // 30) % len(self.jumping_frames_l)
            self.image = self.jumping_frames_l[frame]

        elif self.direction == "Right" and self.state == "Fall":
            frame = (y_pos // 30) % len(self.falling_frames_r)
            self.image = self.falling_frames_r[frame]
        elif self.direction == "Left" and self.state == "Fall":
            frame = (y_pos // 30) % len(self.falling_frames_l)
            self.image = self.falling_frames_l[frame]

        elif self.direction == "Right" and self.state == "Crouch":
            frame = (x_pos // 30) % len(self.crouching_frames_r)
            self.rect.inflate(5, -20)
            # if self.length != 40:
            #     self.rect.inflate(0, 0)
            self.image = self.crouching_frames_r[frame]
        elif self.direction == "Left" and self.state == "Crouch":
            frame = (x_pos // 30) % len(self.crouching_frames_l)
            self.image = self.crouching_frames_l[frame]

        # See if we hit anything
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            # If we are moving right,
            # set our right side to the left side of the item we hit
            if self.change_x > 0:
                self.rect.right = block.rect.left
            elif self.change_x < 0:
                # Otherwise if we are moving left, do the opposite.
                self.rect.left = block.rect.right

        # Move up/down
        self.rect.y += self.change_y

        # Check and see if we hit anything
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:

            # Reset our position based on the top/bottom of the object.
            if self.change_y > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
            elif self.change_y < 0:
                self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom

            # Stop our vertical movement
            self.change_y = 0

            if isinstance(block, MovingPlatform):
                self.rect.x += block.change_x

        self.length = self.rect.right - self.rect.left
        print(self.length)

    def calc_grav(self):
        """ Calculate effect of gravity. """

        # Import the wallslide method
        self.wall_slide()

        if self.change_y == 0:
            self.change_y = 1.75
        else:
            self.change_y += .45

        # See if we are on the ground.
        if self.rect.y >= SCREEN_HEIGHT - self.rect.height and self.change_y >= 0:
            self.change_y = 0
            self.rect.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - self.rect.height
```

I would really appreciate any and all feedback! I'm quite new at this so i'm totally open to being completely and utterly wrong.

Comment: Are the crouching image frames shorter than the upright frames?  The code does not seem to be adjusting the `Sprite.rect` when switching images, so I guess they're all the same size, but maybe this is the problem...

Comment: @Kingsley, is there a pygame function I could use to adjust the width and height on the fly? Or maybe a different way of initializing the player so it's more malleable>

Comment: Yes, there's a couple of ways to do it.  It's possible to just scale the sprite: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21082145/pygame-scaling-a-sprite , but your code looks like it has separate "crouched" images. These are already 20 pixels shorter, so set the `sprite.rect = sprite.image.get_rect()` and re-adjust the position by y += 20 pixels too, since the box-size is smaller, but drawn from the top-left corner.  I don't think you need to scale them.  Just draw them in the correct size, with the correct position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to extend my comment into an answer.

So the program is loading a bunch of sprites from a sprite-sheet.  Let's note that the "standard" character image seems to be `40 x 60` pixels, and the "crouched" image is `45 x 40`. A difference of 20 pixels (and the crouched image is 5 pixels wider too.)

When the sprite goes into "crouched" mode, `self.state == "Crouch"`, the code simply changes the sprite image.  It does not account for the change in position.  If the character "crouched" by pulling it's legs/wheels/tentacles up, and maintains the same height well that's fine.  But if it crouches in the traditional sense, the `Y` position needs be increased by the difference in the sprite-image heights.  This is because PyGame draws sprites from the top-left corner.

The code isn't contained in the question, but whatever operation causes the `self.state` to change to `"Crouch"`, this also needs to adjust the character's `Y` position by `20 pixels` when entering crouch mode, and `-20 pixels` when returning to upright form.  This difference is probably best calculated on the loaded images, rather than as a constant.  Also the sprite `rect` needs to be re-set, since the sprite image size is now different and the collision box needs to be adjusted.

I wrote some quick demo code of how this could work on a sprite.  It is just a coiled spring - which turned out to make a poorly pixelated bitmap, but it illustrates the compressed / uncompressed states.  The important part of the code is the `SpringSprite.crouch()` function, which implements the change in `Y` position by the difference in image height.  Since this code positions on the sprites *centred* rect, obviously the height-changed is halved.

[image: spring.png]   [image: spring_compressed.png]

Pressing Up / Down compresses and un-compress the spring.

```
import pygame

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH  = 400
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 400
GREY = ( 226, 232, 233 )


### 
### Spring sprite that is either upright or compressed 
###
class SpringSprite( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    def __init__( self ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__( self )
        self.upright     = pygame.image.load("spring.png").convert_alpha()            # 64 x 100
        self.compressed  = pygame.image.load("spring_compressed.png").convert_alpha() # 64 x  70
        self.image       = self.upright
        self.rect        = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = ( WINDOW_WIDTH//2, WINDOW_HEIGHT//2 )
        self.crouched    = False
        self.height_delta= ( self.upright.get_height() - self.compressed.get_height() ) // 2 # 15 pixels (centred)

    def crouch( self, crouch=True ):
        if ( self.crouched != crouch ):
            x,y = self.rect.center
            if ( crouch ):
                # We've changed from upright to crouched
                self.image = self.compressed
                y += self.height_delta # difference is centred sprite height
            else:
                # Changed from crouched back to upright
                self.image = self.upright
                y -= self.height_delta # difference is centred-sprite height
            self.crouched    = crouch;
            self.rect        = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.center = ( x, y )

    def update( self ):
        pass

### MAIN
# Open the window
pygame.init()
WINDOW  = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE )
SPRITES = pygame.sprite.Group()
pygame.display.set_caption("Coiled Spring")
# Add a sprite
spring = SpringSprite()
SPRITES.add( spring )


clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False
# Main loop
while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True
        elif ( event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE ):
            WINDOW_WIDTH  = event.w
            WINDOW_HEIGHT = event.h
            WINDOW  = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE )

    # Movement keys
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if ( keys[pygame.K_UP] ):
        spring.crouch( False ) # Upright
    elif ( keys[pygame.K_DOWN] ):
        spring.crouch( True )  # Compressed

    WINDOW.fill( GREY )
    SPRITES.draw( WINDOW )
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick_busy_loop(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you this was a huge help! However, whenever I redraw the sprite.rect it jumps to the top-left corner, how do I get it to stay in it's current position?

Comment: @SmittyBoy_ When the `sprite.rect` is set to the `rect` of the crouching sprite, it needs to also be re-positioned.  Something like `old_x, old_y = self.rect.x, self.rect.y`, then reassign the rect to match the crouched image, and finally re-position the sprite-rect `self.rect = self.crouch_image.get_rect()`, `self.rect.x = old_x`, `self.rect.y = old_y + image_height_difference`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was pulling my hair out with this one and you made it look easy.